# Press back button and reload

Tags: button, reload, back

It is impossible to add `window.location.reload()` on `window.history.go(-1)`? like this

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.history.go(-1), window.location.reload()">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't fire 2 browser events at a time, so you need to put logic.

Fire window.location.reload()

then page on which its taking capture the event and refresh the page, such condition goes basically in your master template or common Js file.
You can achieve this using Jquery.